# $state.go() does not start controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a question that is about $state service.When i click the save button,i close modal and call `$state.go("name") but name state is running(I can see debug) but its controller does not start.Do you have any idea?

Comment: can you post your `angular.config` and the code with the redirection?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

```
$state.go("name",null,{ reload:name});
```

Maybe someone can find useful this answer.

Comment: seems like it's a hack and not a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Controller is defined by a JavaScript constructor function that is used to augment the AngularJS Scope.

By reloading the current route state you can instantiate the current controller again